# Reboot is a stupid tag. There, I said it

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Whenever I see a question that has [reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/reboot) as the only tag, I want to punch a baby. Let's get rid of it. Do it for the kids.

Comment: Why do I care about a bunch of goats?

Comment: I'm glad you didn't say you wanted to punch a PFY :) much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few cases where the question is about [reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/reboot)s (reboot tests, post-patch power cycling, remote reboots/power-cycles/restarts).
I can also argue convincingly that in each of those cases you're not really asking about the *reboot*, but rather all the things that lead up to it (pre-deployment testing, patching, and remote power control / out-of-band management).

So I agree - this tag can probably go.

Answer (score 2):

I just deleted the last of the offending tags. Let's keep an eye on it until it disappears into the inferno.

---

Edit: I'm an idiot and had a filter on my tag searches. There are 150 of these. I think we need a dev for this.

Comment: Can we help - by pushing it in (Frodo-style)...?