# The [restart] tag is a dumb tag (somebody has to say it, it might as well be me)

Tags: discussion

Following on to [this question regarding the death of [reboot](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3015/reboot-is-a-stupid-tag-there-i-said-it/3016#3016), I think [restart](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/restart) can also die a swift and painless death.

Much like reboot I can't think of a convincing time when you would be talking about a *restart* outside the context of something more specific and helpful (Restarting **apache**, Restarting **IIS**, Restarting **SNMPd**, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a tag that does not pass the "if this is the only tag on a question, does it tell me anything useful" test. It's a tag that's best used in conjunction with another tag. We call that a meta tag around here, and we don't like those things.

Get rid of it.

Comment: "[tag:restart], I think you're a *meta* tag. We don' like your kind 'round here, an' I'm gonna send your fingerprints off to Washington..."